# Article with multiple authors model relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am making a wikipedia type blog where an article has multiple authors. For eg: Article 1 is created by john and later edited by steve, bob, jane, etc. Then how can I create the model where if i query Article1.authors it provides me all the authors of Article1 i.e john, steve, bob, jane and also the time when they edited it. It is a personal project for learning. I don't know how to go with the model relation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create an article model with this line :

```
has_many :authors
```

And an Author model with this line :

```
belongs_to :article
```

Thanks to that, you should access to all the author in the article model, so in your article controller, if you write :

```
# all articles
def index
  @articles = Article.all
end

def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  # here you have access to all the authors
  @authors = @article.authors
end
```

I hope this help !

Comment: Can you explain how does the table mapping works? Also will this provide at what time the author edited it?. Sorry beginner here.

Comment: it's verry simple, the has_many / belongs_to allow the model relationship, so you will have one article with many authors, and in your article model you should add a line for timestamp to allow "created_at" and "updated_at", do you use sqlite 3 as DB ?

Comment: Yes I am using sqlite 3.  Is there a way to do with has_many: through or the answer you mentioned is better? I thought since an article can have many authors as well as author can write many articles,  we have many to many and somehow we can use has_many:through

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal I think you should read this : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html you can see The has_and_belongs_to_many Association which provide many to many association